# crontab not executing script

Tags: bash, cron, flock

crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/owner/scripts/upload_main.sh
```

upload_main.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
flock -xn /home/owner/locks/upload.lck -c /home/owner/scripts/upload_silent.sh
```

upload_silent.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
rclone move /home/owner/gdrive/Movies/ gdrive:movies --transfers=6  --no-traverse --quiet
rclone move /home/owner/gdrive/"TV Shows"/ gdrive:tv --transfers=6  --no-traverse --quiet
# remove empty directories
find /home/owner/gdrive/Movies/* -empty -type d -delete 2>/dev/null
find /home/owner/gdrive/"TV Shows"/* -empty -type d -delete 2>/dev/null
```

my crontab is not executing the upload_main.sh script, but running the scripts standalone works. grep CRON shows that the cron is running without any errors.

i'm on a non-root user account ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not redirecting the output of your cronjob to `>/dev/null 2>&1` (which is fine for debug) the output should be "mailed" to your user account. Check `/var/mail` to read your messages and look for the cron output. You should find the error there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a blank line at the end of your crontab, it can prevent it from executing.

I know that wasn't the problem here, but it was the answer for me when I had the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I had to use rclone's full path: `/usr/local/bin/rclone`